# Javascript Intl DatetimeFormatter as (ISO_8601|custom) output pattern

Tags: javascript, icu, intl, ecmascript-intl

I want to use [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) but with custom pattern for output.
I use this method for php version of ICU dateformat and it's work well.

```
$fmt = datefmt_create(
    'fa_IR@calendar=persian',
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    'Asia/Tehran',
    IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL,
    'EEEE d MMMM yyyy HH:mm' // as ISO_8601
);

echo datefmt_format($fmt, time()) . "\n";
// پنجشنبه ۱۰ اردیبهشت ۱۳۹۴ ۱۲:۱۲
```

How can i set pattern as ICU documentation in Intl.DateTimeFormat like php version of ICU date time formatter.

My javascript code

```
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('fa-IR-u-ca-persian').format(new Date()));
```

How can iset ISO_8601 pattern in my javascript format pattern like `EEEE d MMMM yyyy HH:mm` or `MM yy dd` or etc ?

[ISO_8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

[PHP IntlDateFormatter::format](http://php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.format.php)

[ICU Date formatter](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/udat_8h.html#details)

[ICU Date formats](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classSimpleDateFormat.html#details)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

The idea implemented by `Intl` is to give you the "right" format for whatever you request, by the terms of the locale you provide, possibly subject to Unicode extension subtags and similar to configure certain behavioral nuances.  `Intl` doesn't provide any way to specify and use particular formatting patterns.  ISO-8601 format is not something that's guaranteed to be the appropriate format for any particular locale, so you can't use `Intl` to produce it.

If you want to format a date according to a particular pattern slotting in the desired numeric values, you'll have to implement it yourself by calling `Date.prototype.getMonth` and similar functions to get numbers, then slot them into a provided pattern.

Answer (score 0):

you can format your text like this:
result: امروز: پنجشنبه ۲۳ شهریور ۱۴۰۱
just make sure to set `direction: rtl` of HTML tag

```
const date = new Date();

const weekday = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('fa-IR', {weekday: 'long'}).format(date.getDay());
const today = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('fa-IR', {dateStyle: 'long'}).format(date);
const fullDate = `  امروز: ${weekday} ${today}
```